# How to restrict the % functionality of vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have large amount of C code and a large portion of the code is commented out and/or #if 0. When I use the % key to match the open and close brackets of if-else, it matches the commented out code too.
Is there a way or a vim plugin that would not consider the commented out or #if 0 code, while matching brackets.

Currently I am using snipMate and omniComplete vim plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by david, the matchit plugin is able to skip over comments. However, the syntax group that the C syntax script defines for `#if 0` is not configured in the plugin. Create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` and put the following into it:

```
" Make the matchit plugin also skip over sections commented out via #if 0.
let b:match_skip .= '\|cCppOut2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The matchit plugin (included with vim but not enabled) should do this by default for commented out code.  Pretty sure it won't work with `#if 0` code.  Check out `:h matchit` and `:h match_skip`